# How do I insert the filename and header to the beginning of a csv using sed/awk/bash/unix tools?

Tags: awk, sed

My file names are like this.

```
.
├── 10000000.csv
└── 10000001.csv
```

They contain the following.

100..00.csv

```
first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
Chae,Jesusa,Cummings,Female,deifier2040@live.com,775-861-8750,911 Hauser Pike,Moline,Georgia,Cameroon,2016-06-29,2016-07-16,36298,2016-07-17,Acer,493.86,14,354.77,Broken,123.68,898.13
```

100..01.csv

```
first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
Fleta,Rosette,Hurley,Other,tobacconist1857@outlook.com,1-952-701-1210,35 Freelon Arcade,Beaverton,Rhode Island,Cayman Islands,2009-06-08,2009-06-29,39684,2009-07-01,NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980,474.31,16,395.79,Broken,157.53,1088.04
Bennett,Dennis,George,Male,dona1910@live.com,(980) 033-4131,505 Robert C Levy Arcade,Wellington,Louisiana,Mexico,2019-05-09,2019-05-19,37938,2019-05-21,8GB,187.67,16,205.77,Service,170.21,1007.85
Tommye,Pamula,Diaz,Other,dovelet1967@live.com,204.950.4445,1001 Canby Boulevard,Edinburg,Massachusetts,Gambia,2004-05-02,2004-05-24,31364,2004-05-26,Lenovo,137.21,13,193.63,Replacement,246.43,934.31
Albert,Jerrold,Cohen,Other,bolio2036@live.com,+1-(122)-459-8491,1181 Baden Avenue,Menomonee Falls,Texas,Tajikistan,2019-08-03,2019-08-12,37768,2019-08-15,Intel® Iris™ Graphics 6100,396.46,17,223.02,Service,118.53,960.27
Louetta,Collene,Best,Fluid,dinner1922@live.com,1-506-051-7050,923 Barry Viaduct,Laurel,Illinois,St. Barthélemy,2009-03-02,2009-03-06,39557,2009-03-07,AMD Radeon R9 M395X,133.9,11,198.49,Fix,178.54,1055.32
Kandace,Wesley,Diaz,Female,closterium1820@yahoo.com,+1-(777)-098-5414,341 Garlington Run,Santa Maria,New Jersey,Mexico,2005-10-09,2005-10-10,30543,2005-10-14,Samsung,590.29,5,354.85,Service,292.56,1032.22
```

I would like to get the following.

```
customer,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000000,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000000,Chae,Jesusa,Cummings,Female,deifier2040@live.com,775-861-8750,911 Hauser Pike,Moline,Georgia,Cameroon,2016-06-29,2016-07-16,36298,2016-07-17,Acer,493.86,14,354.77,Broken,123.68,898.13

customer,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000001,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000001,Fleta,Rosette,Hurley,Other,tobacconist1857@outlook.com,1-952-701-1210,35 Freelon Arcade,Beaverton,Rhode Island,Cayman Islands,2009-06-08,2009-06-29,39684,2009-07-01,NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980,474.31,16,395.79,Broken,157.53,1088.04
10000001,Bennett,Dennis,George,Male,dona1910@live.com,(980) 033-4131,505 Robert C Levy Arcade,Wellington,Louisiana,Mexico,2019-05-09,2019-05-19,37938,2019-05-21,8GB,187.67,16,205.77,Service,170.21,1007.85
10000001,Tommye,Pamula,Diaz,Other,dovelet1967@live.com,204.950.4445,1001 Canby Boulevard,Edinburg,Massachusetts,Gambia,2004-05-02,2004-05-24,31364,2004-05-26,Lenovo,137.21,13,193.63,Replacement,246.43,934.31
10000001,Albert,Jerrold,Cohen,Other,bolio2036@live.com,+1-(122)-459-8491,1181 Baden Avenue,Menomonee Falls,Texas,Tajikistan,2019-08-03,2019-08-12,37768,2019-08-15,Intel® Iris™ Graphics 6100,396.46,17,223.02,Service,118.53,960.27
10000001,Louetta,Collene,Best,Fluid,dinner1922@live.com,1-506-051-7050,923 Barry Viaduct,Laurel,Illinois,St. Barthélemy,2009-03-02,2009-03-06,39557,2009-03-07,AMD Radeon R9 M395X,133.9,11,198.49,Fix,178.54,1055.32
10000001,Kandace,Wesley,Diaz,Female,closterium1820@yahoo.com,+1-(777)-098-5414,341 Garlington Run,Santa Maria,New Jersey,Mexico,2005-10-09,2005-10-10,30543,2005-10-14,Samsung,590.29,5,354.85,Service,292.56,1032.22
```

I have done this to get it right for the data. But I can't figure out how to do it for the header.

`awk ' gsub(".csv","",FILENAME); {print FILENAME (NF?",":"") $0}' *.csv`

```
first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000000,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000000,Chae,Jesusa,Cummings,Female,deifier2040@live.com,775-861-8750,911 Hauser Pike,Moline,Georgia,Cameroon,2016-06-29,2016-07-16,36298,2016-07-17,Acer,493.86,14,354.77,Broken,123.68,898.13

first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000001,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000001,Fleta,Rosette,Hurley,Other,tobacconist1857@outlook.com,1-952-701-1210,35 Freelon Arcade,Beaverton,Rhode Island,Cayman Islands,2009-06-08,2009-06-29,39684,2009-07-01,NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980,474.31,16,395.79,Broken,157.53,1088.04
10000001,Bennett,Dennis,George,Male,dona1910@live.com,(980) 033-4131,505 Robert C Levy Arcade,Wellington,Louisiana,Mexico,2019-05-09,2019-05-19,37938,2019-05-21,8GB,187.67,16,205.77,Service,170.21,1007.85
10000001,Tommye,Pamula,Diaz,Other,dovelet1967@live.com,204.950.4445,1001 Canby Boulevard,Edinburg,Massachusetts,Gambia,2004-05-02,2004-05-24,31364,2004-05-26,Lenovo,137.21,13,193.63,Replacement,246.43,934.31
10000001,Albert,Jerrold,Cohen,Other,bolio2036@live.com,+1-(122)-459-8491,1181 Baden Avenue,Menomonee Falls,Texas,Tajikistan,2019-08-03,2019-08-12,37768,2019-08-15,Intel® Iris™ Graphics 6100,396.46,17,223.02,Service,118.53,960.27
10000001,Louetta,Collene,Best,Fluid,dinner1922@live.com,1-506-051-7050,923 Barry Viaduct,Laurel,Illinois,St. Barthélemy,2009-03-02,2009-03-06,39557,2009-03-07,AMD Radeon R9 M395X,133.9,11,198.49,Fix,178.54,1055.32
10000001,Kandace,Wesley,Diaz,Female,closterium1820@yahoo.com,+1-(777)-098-5414,341 Garlington Run,Santa Maria,New Jersey,Mexico,2005-10-09,2005-10-10,30543,2005-10-14,Samsung,590.29,5,354.85,Service,292.56,1032.22
```

But if I do this with sed, I can do the header for the first file alone, but not the data OR the remaining files.

`sed '1s/.*/customer,&/' *.csv`

```
customer,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
Chae,Jesusa,Cummings,Female,deifier2040@live.com,775-861-8750,911 Hauser Pike,Moline,Georgia,Cameroon,2016-06-29,2016-07-16,36298,2016-07-17,Acer,493.86,14,354.77,Broken,123.68,898.13
first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
Fleta,Rosette,Hurley,Other,tobacconist1857@outlook.com,1-952-701-1210,35 Freelon Arcade,Beaverton,Rhode Island,Cayman Islands,2009-06-08,2009-06-29,39684,2009-07-01,NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980,474.31,16,395.79,Broken,157.53,1088.04
Bennett,Dennis,George,Male,dona1910@live.com,(980) 033-4131,505 Robert C Levy Arcade,Wellington,Louisiana,Mexico,2019-05-09,2019-05-19,37938,2019-05-21,8GB,187.67,16,205.77,Service,170.21,1007.85
Tommye,Pamula,Diaz,Other,dovelet1967@live.com,204.950.4445,1001 Canby Boulevard,Edinburg,Massachusetts,Gambia,2004-05-02,2004-05-24,31364,2004-05-26,Lenovo,137.21,13,193.63,Replacement,246.43,934.31
Albert,Jerrold,Cohen,Other,bolio2036@live.com,+1-(122)-459-8491,1181 Baden Avenue,Menomonee Falls,Texas,Tajikistan,2019-08-03,2019-08-12,37768,2019-08-15,Intel® Iris™ Graphics 6100,396.46,17,223.02,Service,118.53,960.27
Louetta,Collene,Best,Fluid,dinner1922@live.com,1-506-051-7050,923 Barry Viaduct,Laurel,Illinois,St. Barthélemy,2009-03-02,2009-03-06,39557,2009-03-07,AMD Radeon R9 M395X,133.9,11,198.49,Fix,178.54,1055.32
Kandace,Wesley,Diaz,Female,closterium1820@yahoo.com,+1-(777)-098-5414,341 Garlington Run,Santa Maria,New Jersey,Mexico,2005-10-09,2005-10-10,30543,2005-10-14,Samsung,590.29,5,354.85,Service,292.56,1032.22
```

I am open to any of the linux tools available. I would like to keep python as a secondary tool. This is just an illustration. I have a billion files.

I would also like to replace the files inplace. I know I can do this with `-i` for `sed` but I don't know for `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}' 10000000.csv
customer,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000000,Chae,Jesusa,Cummings,Female,deifier2040@live.com,775-861-8750,911 Hauser Pike,Moline,Georgia,Cameroon,2016-06-29,2016-07-16,36298,2016-07-17,Acer,493.86,14,354.77,Broken,123.68,898.13
```

so with any awk you could do:

```
for file in *.csv; do
    awk 'script' "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"
done
```

or with GNU awk for "inplace" editing:

```
$ tail -n +1 10000000.csv 10000001.csv
==> 10000000.csv <==
first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
Chae,Jesusa,Cummings,Female,deifier2040@live.com,775-861-8750,911 Hauser Pike,Moline,Georgia,Cameroon,2016-06-29,2016-07-16,36298,2016-07-17,Acer,493.86,14,354.77,Broken,123.68,898.13

==> 10000001.csv <==
first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
Fleta,Rosette,Hurley,Other,tobacconist1857@outlook.com,1-952-701-1210,35 Freelon Arcade,Beaverton,Rhode Island,Cayman Islands,2009-06-08,2009-06-29,39684,2009-07-01,NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980,474.31,16,395.79,Broken,157.53,1088.04
Bennett,Dennis,George,Male,dona1910@live.com,(980) 033-4131,505 Robert C Levy Arcade,Wellington,Louisiana,Mexico,2019-05-09,2019-05-19,37938,2019-05-21,8GB,187.67,16,205.77,Service,170.21,1007.85
Tommye,Pamula,Diaz,Other,dovelet1967@live.com,204.950.4445,1001 Canby Boulevard,Edinburg,Massachusetts,Gambia,2004-05-02,2004-05-24,31364,2004-05-26,Lenovo,137.21,13,193.63,Replacement,246.43,934.31
Albert,Jerrold,Cohen,Other,bolio2036@live.com,+1-(122)-459-8491,1181 Baden Avenue,Menomonee Falls,Texas,Tajikistan,2019-08-03,2019-08-12,37768,2019-08-15,Intel® Iris™ Graphics 6100,396.46,17,223.02,Service,118.53,960.27
Louetta,Collene,Best,Fluid,dinner1922@live.com,1-506-051-7050,923 Barry Viaduct,Laurel,Illinois,St. Barthélemy,2009-03-02,2009-03-06,39557,2009-03-07,AMD Radeon R9 M395X,133.9,11,198.49,Fix,178.54,1055.32
Kandace,Wesley,Diaz,Female,closterium1820@yahoo.com,+1-(777)-098-5414,341 Garlington Run,Santa Maria,New Jersey,Mexico,2005-10-09,2005-10-10,30543,2005-10-14,Samsung,590.29,5,354.85,Service,292.56,1032.22
```

.

```
$ awk -i inplace -v OFS=',' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}' 10000000.csv 10000001.csv
```

.

```
$ tail -n +1 10000000.csv 10000001.csv
==> 10000000.csv <==
customer,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000000,Chae,Jesusa,Cummings,Female,deifier2040@live.com,775-861-8750,911 Hauser Pike,Moline,Georgia,Cameroon,2016-06-29,2016-07-16,36298,2016-07-17,Acer,493.86,14,354.77,Broken,123.68,898.13

==> 10000001.csv <==
customer,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000001,Fleta,Rosette,Hurley,Other,tobacconist1857@outlook.com,1-952-701-1210,35 Freelon Arcade,Beaverton,Rhode Island,Cayman Islands,2009-06-08,2009-06-29,39684,2009-07-01,NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980,474.31,16,395.79,Broken,157.53,1088.04
10000001,Bennett,Dennis,George,Male,dona1910@live.com,(980) 033-4131,505 Robert C Levy Arcade,Wellington,Louisiana,Mexico,2019-05-09,2019-05-19,37938,2019-05-21,8GB,187.67,16,205.77,Service,170.21,1007.85
10000001,Tommye,Pamula,Diaz,Other,dovelet1967@live.com,204.950.4445,1001 Canby Boulevard,Edinburg,Massachusetts,Gambia,2004-05-02,2004-05-24,31364,2004-05-26,Lenovo,137.21,13,193.63,Replacement,246.43,934.31
10000001,Albert,Jerrold,Cohen,Other,bolio2036@live.com,+1-(122)-459-8491,1181 Baden Avenue,Menomonee Falls,Texas,Tajikistan,2019-08-03,2019-08-12,37768,2019-08-15,Intel® Iris™ Graphics 6100,396.46,17,223.02,Service,118.53,960.27
10000001,Louetta,Collene,Best,Fluid,dinner1922@live.com,1-506-051-7050,923 Barry Viaduct,Laurel,Illinois,St. Barthélemy,2009-03-02,2009-03-06,39557,2009-03-07,AMD Radeon R9 M395X,133.9,11,198.49,Fix,178.54,1055.32
10000001,Kandace,Wesley,Diaz,Female,closterium1820@yahoo.com,+1-(777)-098-5414,341 Garlington Run,Santa Maria,New Jersey,Mexico,2005-10-09,2005-10-10,30543,2005-10-14,Samsung,590.29,5,354.85,Service,292.56,1032.22
```

Comment: Hi, I tried out your solution. Works really well. And it's blazingly faster than sed. Can you please explain why this solution is faster than the solution (using sed) which I have accepted?

Comment: Apparently in my PC I have GNU awk, but in my VirtualBox I have mawk. That's why I couldn't run the `inplace` initially.

Comment: With my script the shell starts 1 process and it operates on all files at once. With the find+sed+xargs+sed approach the shell is starting a new process for every input file (or mayb every group of a few input files depending how xargs decides to handle the calls to sed) and then a couple more - that takes time.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my edit for the test results using your script, in my other question.

Comment: For posterity, this is that other question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/533626/133219

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are no nasty filenames, something like this works:

```
find . -name '*.csv' -printf "%f\n" |
sed 's/.csv$//' |
xargs -I{} sed -i '1s/^/customer,/; 1!s/^/{},/' {}.csv
```

First I find all the `csv` files and print only the filename.
Then remove the `.csv` suffix from files.
Then I run xargs, so for each file...
...add to the beginning of the line `customer,` if it's the first line, otherwise I add the filename without `.csv` to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with awk:

```
find . -name \*.csv -exec awk '{ gsub(".csv","",FILENAME); if (NR == 1) {print "customer," $0; next; } else print FILENAME (NF?",":"") $0}' {} \;
```

if you want a blank line before next file:

```
find . -name \*.csv -exec awk '{ gsub(".csv","",FILENAME); if (NR == 1) {print "customer," $0; next; } else print FILENAME (NF?",":"") $0} END { print ""; }' {} \;
```

this find file with csv extension and execute awk script on each.

Answer (score 1):

For a single file you can do

```
awk '(FNR==1){f=FILENAME+0; print "customer,",$0; next}
     {print f","$0 }' input.csv > output.csv
```

For all CSV files in one go

```
awk '(FNR==1){f=FILENAME+0; print "customer,",$0; next}
     {print f","$0 > (FILENAME".new") }' *.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sed -i '1 i\anything' file`.

`sed` is a replace

`-i` is to replace in place

`1` indicates line 1, aka the header

`i\` means prepend

`file` is the filename, or matching pattern for your files.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. I already know the use of `-i`. That's like a secondary thing for me. I don't know if there's an equivalent for `awk`. Primary objective for me is to do the appending in the file. Btw, welcome to SO. :)

Comment: Just like GNU sed has `-i`, GNU awk has `-i inplace`.

Comment: @EdMorton when I do `/inplace` in my man page there are no results found.

Comment: Then you aren't looking in the man page for GNU awk. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace

Comment: @EdMorton I think I have `mawk` instead of `gawk`

Comment: If you have or can get GNU sed then you have or can get GNU awk and if you're doing `sed -i 'script'` then you are using GNU sed. Get gawk - it has a TON of extremely useful features above POSIX awk.